# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Degrades every time I update - Stays down

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

When I update my instance, I use the EB Command Line Tools. I push my instance to my CodeCommit git, and then deploy my code using the `eb deploy` command. Nearly every time I do this, my envronment status changes to degraded/severe with the instance that is running giving the error `Following services are not running: proxy.` It will spin up more instances based on my auto scaling policy (tied to health), and sometimes after 2-3 new instances, I will get one that is "OK"

My environment is configured as `64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v2.2.0 running PHP 7.0`. It is auto load balancing and auto scaling on average netowrk out. It is running t1.micro in Any availability zone, and the software configuration is as follows: **Log publication**: On;
**Allow URL fopen**: On;
**Display errors**: Off;
**Document root**: /http/;
**Max execution time**: 60;
**Memory limit**: 256M;
**Zlib output compression**: Off;

What could cause this?

Comment: All instances and any newly created instances are spun up in the us-east-1a zone

Comment: did you resolve this? i am facing the same issue

Comment: I couldn't. I ended up starting a completely new application. It now works great, but it was a real pain to transfer because I had a RDS inside of my EB application.

Comment: did you start the new app from the CLI or the console? i have done many apps over the years but never faced this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh`. Note that `01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh` might have a different name for you.

In there you need to change your proxy check if you're not using `apache/httpd` to `nginx`, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xe
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy nginx
```

If you are using `apache/httpd`, it means that there's something wrong with your apache runtime instance or process. Make sure the pid file is where is should be for the health check.

Comment: I don't tweak anything on my instances and haven't done for a number of years but as soon as i downloaded the new eb command line tools for deployment i get the same issue as reported above

Answer (score 1):

We can set a file inside the .ebextensions directory as bellow. when you see the error `Following services are not running: proxy.`

.ebextensions/01_fix_proxy.config
contents:

```
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_monitor_httpd_pid.sh":
  mode: "000755"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
    #!/bin/bash
    set -xe
    /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/healthd-track-pidfile --proxy nginx
```